# Gatsby build path issues

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, path, graphql, gatsby

Having issues running gatsby build with gatsby-starter-wordpress-advanced theme:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Tobias\Desktop\Gatsby\gatsby-starter-wordpress-advanced\.template-cache\tmp-\.js'"
```

I figured this might be a problem with the path. The path should rather look like:

```
writing tmp-new-page/ template: open '.template-cache/tmp-new-page.js'
```

See repo: https://github.com/henrikwirth/gatsby-starter-wordpress-advanced/blob/master/create/utils.js

Line 53 you find the function createPageWithTemplate. I've tried console.log(page.uri) to see what's going on. It outputs the filename correctly. I've also tried with gatsby clean to clear the cache. It seems to be some kind of backslash issue where the path comes with a \ .js at the end instead of sample-page.js:

```
no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Tobias\Desktop\Gatsby\gatsby-starter-wordpress-advanced\.template-cache\sample-page\.js'
```

Comment: unfortunately gatsby clean didn't do any difference... Still the same error.

Comment: `gatsby-clean` deletes .cache, but not .template-cache, as far as I know. Did you try to manually delete it and reinstall your dependencies (`rm -rf node_modules && yarn`) before running again?

Comment: unfortunately still the same error. I deleted .template-cache folder & node_module folder and ran npm install.

Comment: Sorry to hear that - did you follow the [tutorial](https://dev.to/nevernull/overview-guide-to-gatsby-wordpress-starter-advanced-with-previews-i18n-and-more-583l) attached to the [starter you're trying to use](https://github.com/henrikwirth/gatsby-starter-wordpress-advanced)? If you did, you might want to open an issue on the starter's repo, as this issue seems very specific to it. Alternatively, you could look into other starters on the [Gatsby Starter Library](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/?v=2)

Comment: Thanks, Robin. I just scrolled through the comment section on blog post tutorial and seems like I'm not the only one having issues: https://dev.to/ibjorn/comment/kj14 - I'll open an issue on the starter's repo :)

Comment: Great - when you figure it out, it would be amazing if you could post an answer here too! Future visitors will thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue have been resolved. The problem was related to update in WPGraphQL WordPress plugin. Had to update the paths, because the page.uri is different in the newer versions of WPGraphQL. Before it was just: some-page now it is /some-page/.

Secondly in the page template creation process the theme was using the uri, therefore, this messed up the paths for the template files. This has been switched to page.slug instead now and some extra checks, to make sure the frontPage is not ending up producing a wrong path.

The master branch of the starter theme have been updated.